# Crontab custom shell execute cron

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I want to make my cron command execute from a custom shell as follows:

```
SHELL=/bin/cron-launcher.sh
* * * * * test  echo "toto" >> /tmp/shell.log
```

The issue is that the file /tmp/shell.log is empty if i specify my own shell.

The content of my custom shell is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

#Script use to launch cron tasks

set -e

SHELL="/bin/bash -e"
LOGDIR="/var/log/cronlauncher/"

echo "$USER" > /tmp/test.log
```

The user used to launch the cron is very well outputted to the file /tmp/test.log but the cron command `echo "toto"` from the cron is never outputted to the file `/tmp/shell.log` .

How do I do to make the custom shell execute the cron command correctly.

That is to make the `cron-launcher.sh` script act as a wrapper.

Below is a extract of my /var/log/cron:

> Dec 26 15:55:01 bf7fe8653ac9 CROND[658]: (test) CMD ( echo "toto" >>
>   /tmp/shell.

Comment: `cron-launcher.sh` is no shell, it‘s a bash script.

Comment: That true, but i want to make it 'act' like shell

Comment: Or more simply to act as a wrapper between the shell

Comment: 1) and what is `test` ? 2) is `/bin/cron-launcher.sh` listed in `/etc/shells` ?

Comment: 1) `test` is the user test
2) No it is not listed in the `/etc/shells`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by executing the 2nd argument parsed to the shell `cron-launcher.sh`

The fac is that the command `echo "toto" >> /tmp/shell.log` from the cron

`SHELL=/bin/cron-launcher.sh
* * * * * test  echo "toto" >> /tmp/shell.log`

is parsed as `$2` in the shell `cron-launcher`.

Hence I juste had to modify my code as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Script use to launch cron tasks

SHELL="/bin/bash"
LOGDIR="/var/log/cronlauncher/"

#echo "$USER" >> /tmp/test.log
COMMAND="$2"
eval $COMMAND
```